# In web development lingo, what does it mean to "serve a static file"?

Tags: web-applications

What is a static file? What does it mean "to serve static files"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The opposite of a dynamic file :)  It means that the file content will be sent to the client (usually a browser) as is without server intervention.  By contrast, a dynamic file is parsed by the server which then renders a new set of data based on the dynamic file template.  A dynamic file will typically use some form of server-side code to let the server know what type of modifications need to be made.

Answer (score 4):

A static file is something like:

- `index.html`
- `style.css`
- `script.js`
- `image.jpg`

Basically, anything which is not a PHP script, and anything which is not dynamically generated by your web server.

Answer (score 2):

It's a file that doesn't change. There isn't any logic running to generate what you see as there would be on a page with "dynamic" content.

Answer (score 1):

It means that server will not be used to produce a file.

When you ask for a *.css or an image - the server does not intervene, whereas if you ask for *.php file a server needs to generate it before giving it back.

http://support.exsitewebware.com/cgi/page.cgi/articles.html/Content_Management/Static_vs_Dynamic_Content

Answer (score 0):

When people talk about static/dynamic files, they talk about how the file is GENERATED.

A file like `index.html` can be a "dynamic" file, in a sense that it is dynamically GENERATED (using a server which reached out to a database, some API, some code etc.)